# Jest globalSetup with typescript is not recognizing .ts extension when importing modules "Unknown file extension ".ts""

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

My tests are written in typescript and all works fine, now I want to have a `globalSetup`.

I added the globalSetup and worked as well, but as soon I import a module I get:

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Jest: Got error running globalSetup reason: Unknown file extension ".ts"
```

Doesn't seems to be just because of typescript, because when I import a function from another typescript file it works.

The problem is when I import from `node_modules`

`jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  roots: ['<rootDir>/test'],
  testMatch: ['**/*.test.ts'],
  globalSetup: './config/testSetup.ts',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
  }
};
```

jest version `v27.5.1`
typescript version `v4.8.4`